# How to display unlisted group names through vf page in desktop and listed and private groups in sf1 i.e. mobile

Tags: apex, visualforce, chatter

I want to display the unlisted group names when the vf page is previewed in desktop and listed and private group names when opened in mobile(salesforce1). How can be this possible?

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy. We need to call an action function from a java script function by differentiating sf1 and desktop browser in  java script function  and in action function we can query the list with if else condition. I mean, if it is browser it should display unlisted group names or else it should display listed and private group names.